# How to correctly cut text via regular expression?

Tags: regex, formatting

how to correctly cut string from this text:

```
Hi there,
Here is your info :  
Track & Trace code: BI812102
http://localhost:5006/BI812102/3333AX
Thank you!
```

I need to cut only single `BI812102`

Here is what I tried to do:

```
\BR([a-fA-F]|[0-9]){0,9}
```

Comment: With `\bBI[a-fA-F0-9]{0,9}\b`? See https://regex101.com/r/LvKKHj/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\bBI[a-fA-F0-9]{0,9}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LvKKHj/1).

- `\b` - the previous char must be a char other than a letter, digit or underscore or it must be start of string position
- `BI` - a `BI` string
- `[a-fA-F0-9]{0,9}` - zero to nine hex chars
- `\b` - end of string or the next char must be a non-word char (not a letter, digit or `_`).